# How do I modify a Hubspot javascript form that is system generated

Tags: javascript, hubspot

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to extend a Hubspot form in their CMS to get some additional functionality out of it.

Unfortunately I can not edit the code they have in the CMS so thought there might be a way to add some javascript after their code to add in what I want to do.

The code they generate looks like this:

```
      hbspt.forms.create({ 
        portalId: '435515',
        formId: '19046100-d845-4f9c-96cf-974286fc6b45', 
      });
```

I'm wanting to grab the form data after submit so it needs to be like this:

```
      hbspt.forms.create({ 
        portalId: '435515',
        formId: '19046100-d845-4f9c-96cf-974286fc6b45',
        onFormSubmit: function($data) {
          console.log( $("input[name=firstname]").val() );
        }    
      });
```

But I can not edit the code they generate. Is there a way to add the onFormSubmit to this function without editing the code they are generating.

So something like: (this doesn't work)

```
    //Their original code
    <script>    
      hbspt.forms.create({ 
        portalId: '435515',
        formId: '19046100-d845-4f9c-96cf-974286fc6b45',   
      });
    </script> 

    //My added function
    <script> 
        onFormSubmit: function($data) {
          console.log( $("input[name=firstname]").val() );
        }          
    </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: You mention 'But I can not edit the code they generate.'  Are you using the embeddable form html/JS snippet or strictly the COS module in Design manager/editing tools?

Comment: Also -- it will be helpful to know how you plan to use values from inputs on submit.  Ex: Manipulating input field values will require use of .change() in the callback force-update the form's state.

Comment: I'm using the COS forms... As far as I can see you can't edit this code / module.

I want to grab the form data (after submit so it passes validation etc) and the post it off somewhere else via AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option #1:** Use embeddable forms in COS rich text modules -- sounds backwards I know, but its viable.  This gives you access to **onFormSubmit**, a valid option for embeddable HubSpot forms per the developer docs: http://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/advanced_form_options

**Option #2 (Requires HubSpot Pro or Enterprise):** Trigger a workflow on form submission and include a webhook as a step -- the payload cannot be modified, but it send the entirety of the contact record to an endpoint of your choice: http://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/workflows/webhook_information

**Option #3 (Works on all product tiers -- paid, but minimal $$):** Use Zapier.com to connect HubSpot to other SaaS platforms.  Zapier also includes a method of customizing webhook payloads to send the desired data to your final destination.

Comment: Thanks - I had tried option 1 but wasn't ideal for the user as they need to still manually add the embed code in. I was wanting to piggy back off all the existing forms. 

Option 2 however sounds like it will work well. Thank you

Comment: Can confirm option 2 works almost to well - So much data! Thanks

Comment: Great to hear! Make sure you set the workflow to fire every time a contact meets the criteria/submits a form, not just the first time :)

Answer (score 5):

Another way, apart from with what @Kirk H mentioned, could be to monitor the event messages of the page and perform actions when a message is published and is related to HubSpot form, such as a form submission.

For sure, it is not the optimal solution as you are practically monitoring the events of the page in general, but it does not require any external libraries, services or any Pro/Enterprise accounts in terms of cost, and should do the work in simple and not heavy workload scenarios.

For instance, this could be useful for integration with other systems, [such as Google Tag Manager](https://www.3whitehats.com/knowledge/tracking-hubspot-forms-google-tag-manager/):

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  // An event regarding HS form occured, and it is a form submission here.
  if(event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' &&
    event.data.eventName === 'onFormSubmitted') {
    window.dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'hubspot-form-success',
      'hs-form-guid': event.data.id
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [HubSpot global form events](https://developers.hubspot.com/global-form-events):

```
window.addEventListener('message', event => {
  if (
    event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback'
    && event.data.eventName === 'onFormSubmit'
  ) {
    console.log("Form Submitted!");
  }
});
```

If you have multiple forms on your page, you can also check for its *id*, with `event.data.id`.